# Applying tidymodels fitted model to new, unlabeled data

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, tidymodels

I've been reading articles and documentation, browsing youtube videos, etc and I cannot find a process to use a tidymodels workflow for an on-going basis.

For example, https://tune.tidymodels.org/reference/last_fit.html prescribes "The next step would be to fit using the entire training set and verify performance using the test data."

I want to tune a model with training/test data, create the last_fit, and then apply it to data for which the performance cannot be verified because it is not labeled/does not have an outcome.

In my particular case, I'm creating a classification model to predict whether a particular product subscription will churn or renew. In advance, say 30 days, I want to create a prediction for a given subscription's outcome (or for all of the subscriptions that will expire in the next 30 days).

As far as I can tell, `rsample` does not include a way to split the data in this manner or else I would do that. I feel like I must be missing something simple but I can only find examples where people are using completely labeled data.

Comment: To apply a fitted model to new data, you'd use the generic predict() function. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

You can exact the final fitted model/workflow from the result of `last_fit()` using `extract_fit_parsnip()` and `extract_workflow()` respectively.

```r
library(tidymodels)

set.seed(6735)
tr_te_split <- initial_split(mtcars)

rec_spec <- recipe(mpg ~ ., data = training(tr_te_split)) %>%
  step_normalize(all_predictors())

lin_mod <- linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("lm")

wf_spec <-
 workflow() %>%
 add_recipe(rec_spec) %>%
 add_model(lin_mod)

wf_res <- last_fit(wf_spec, split = tr_te_split)

final_wf <- wf_res %>%
  extract_workflow()
final_wf
#> ══ Workflow [trained] ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Recipe
#> Model: linear_reg()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 1 Recipe Step
#> 
#> • step_normalize()
#> 
#> ── Model ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 
#> Call:
#> stats::lm(formula = ..y ~ ., data = data)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)          cyl         disp           hp         drat           wt  
#>   19.387500    -1.167165    -1.311400    -0.005379     0.237784    -0.602792  
#>        qsec           vs           am         gear         carb  
#>    0.262839     0.758393     2.791441    -0.516713    -1.773907
```

Then to simulate unlabeled data, we create some random cars. Note that this data set doesn't have the response variable `mpg`.

```r
random_cars <- mtcars %>%
  select(-mpg) %>%
  map_dfc(sample)

random_cars
#> # A tibble: 32 × 10
#>      cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     8  79     205  3.07  2.46  18.6     0     0     3     4
#>  2     8 460     180  3.77  2.77  18.0     1     0     4     1
#>  3     8  95.1   175  3     3.22  18.9     0     1     4     4
#>  4     8 145     123  4.93  3.44  14.6     1     1     4     1
#>  5     8 360      52  4.11  3.44  20.0     1     1     4     3
#>  6     4 276.    230  4.08  2.78  14.5     0     0     4     4
#>  7     6 472      95  3.9   3.44  19.5     0     0     4     2
#>  8     6  78.7   215  2.76  3.15  17.3     0     1     3     4
#>  9     8 225     113  3.92  1.62  18.5     1     0     5     1
#> 10     8 160     175  3.7   2.62  17.4     1     0     3     2
#> # … with 22 more rows
```

We can now predict on this workflow with `predict()`

```r
predict(final_wf, random_cars)
#> # A tibble: 32 × 1
#>    .pred
#>    <dbl>
#>  1  17.4
#>  2  17.4
#>  3  21.9
#>  4  26.2
#>  5  22.2
#>  6  16.9
#>  7  15.9
#>  8  23.8
#>  9  20.1
#> 10  20.2
#> # … with 22 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks, `extract_workflow()` and making that final wf was what I needed and hadn't found. Now the issue I have is that some of the transformations from the recipe that I used on the split data need to be done on my prediction set. For simplicity, can focus on one: I use `step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors())`. How do I apply that to my new data? I tried making a copy of the recipe, applying it to my new data, and then a workflow from that but the object it creates isn't a workflow and I can't added it to `final_wf`

Comment: The preprocessing steps in the recipe will be performed automatically when you `predict()` the workflow

Comment: I tried it before and am getting a warning message for "novel levels" in `sub_id`, which shouldn't be used as a predictor because I have this in my recipe: `update_role(sub_id, renewal_decision_date, next_renewal_decision_date, new_role = "ID")`. So I was assuming the recipe wasn't getting applied.